# How to add Ubuntu on second Hard Drive to Windows Boot Manager?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bitlocker, boot-manager

I need to add Ubuntu on a second Hard Drive to the Windows Boot Manager, because BitLocker doesn't work with GRUB and the Boot Device Selection is secured by the UEFI password. I tried to copy the Ubuntu Bootloader to Y: on the first Drive but the .bin file wasn't found by the Boot Manager or is corrupted. So i want to add the Ubuntu's Bootloader directly to the Windows Boot Manager. Is this possible and how?

[My Hard Drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZtiB.png)

On Datenträger 1 is Windows installed and on the second one Ubuntu.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-option

Comment: This is a different problem. Grub is installed on the second Hard Drive. I need to use the Windows Boot Manager because BitLocker doesn't run with Grub, because BitLocker locks Windows, because the normal Boot order is interrupted by GRUB. Easy BCD isn't working, because I'am using UEFI.